# Confidence Region for a Nonlinear Parameter Fit

Tags: python, statistics, data-analysis, confidence-interval

I have some data in hand that I did a non linear parameter fit to. Now I want to plot the joint confidence regions of the fitted parameters. I want something like this:

[image: Adam G. Riess et al 2004 ApJ 607 665]

How could I do that with python? Thank you and have a good day :)